# -Infinity values in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to sum 561 logs.
They look like these:

```
-7.314254939475686
-7.656004233197743
-4.816276208120333
-8.426112454893817
-4.771824445549499
-9.34240318676797
```

So they're not big numbers. However, when I proceed with summing them I get this:

```
-2668.179647264475
-2674.7747795369874
-2679.18920466334
-2683.9724816026214
-2690.3342661536453
-Infinity
-Infinity
```

The code that does it is:

```
double probspam=0;

for(int j=0;j<words.size();j++)
{
    probspam+= Math.log(spam.getClassProbability(words.get(j)));

}
```

Do you have any idea of how to get around the -Infinity issue and why it happens? Thank you

Comment: I would guess that the numbers coming out of `Math.log` aren't what you think they are.  Add a temporary variable to hold the result before summation, and print it to the screen inside the loop.

Comment: So, you're not summing them, but rather summing their logs.

Comment: Why Math.log ? That's where your infinity is coming from anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some values, `spam.getClassProbability()` returns `0.0`: [see the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29):

> If the argument is positive zero or negative zero, then the result is negative infinity.

Comment: one question, why even though cp is of type double I have to use the cast operator or otherwise get 0?  cp=(double) 1/(this.sizeEvidence+this.counter.size());

Comment: Because all operands are integers. Use `1.0/...` instead to get doubles.

Answer (score 2):

The [Javadoc for Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29) explains why you get `-Infinity` as a result:

> If the argument is positive zero or negative zero, then the result is negative infinity.

You should check your values for zeros, or filter them out prior to applying the `log` function.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the value of `spam.getClassProbability(words.get(j))` is zero at some point.

`Math.log(0.0)` returns negative infinity (as the API documentation says).

Answer (score 1):

One of your spam candidates is getting a zero from `getClassProbability`:

```
System.out.println(Math.log(0));
```

Output:

```
-Infinity
```

This is a special reserved double value, and any operation on it also gives `-Infinity`, so once it hits the zero, your summing variable will stay `-Infinity`

To "fix" it, do this:

```
double wordProbSpam = spam.getClassProbability(words.get(j));
probspam += wordProbSpam > 0 ? Math.log(wordProbSpam) : 0;
```

Frankly, I think your approach is flawed. I would be simply summing the result of getClassProbability(), not summing its *log*, because for number between 0-1 the log is negative, which will do weird things to the sum.

Comment: Summing the logs of probabilities is a standard and well regarded statistical technique to avoid computational underflow. It's usage is probably correct here.

Comment: @SimonG. I use the logs, as you correctly recognized, to avoid the underflow of the product.

Answer (score 1):

If the class probability for one word is zero, then you add `-Infinity` to your sum.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've already had this questioned in general - you are taking the log of 0.0. Even if your getClassProbability() is perfect, numerical underflow may still mean it returns zero when mathematically speaking the result was non-zero.

One option is to replace all zeros with the value of Double.ulp(0.0). This is the smallest non-zero value Java can represent (4.9e-324) and has a log around -744.44. This recognises the game breaking concept of a zero probability. After all spammers are very clever so the probability will never truly be zero.